# nestjs+ swagger file upload with other dto

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I have a difficult part while using nestjs and swagger, so I ask a question.

```js
@Post('import')
  @ApiConsumes('multipart/form-data')
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileFieldsInterceptor(
      [
        { name: 'file', maxCount: 5 },
      ],
      {
        storage: multerS3({
          s3: s3,
          bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKET_NAME,
          acl: 'public-read',
          key: function (request, file, cb) {
            cb(
              null,
              `test/${file.fieldname}/${uuid()}_${file.originalname
              }`,
            );
          },
        }),
        fileFilter: extensionHelper,
      },
    ),
  )
  async upload(
    @Body() dto: AddDto,
    @UploadedFiles() file?: Express.MulterS3.File[],
  ): Promise<void> {
    
  }
```

```js
export class AddDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  firstName?: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  lastName: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => AdditionalDto)
  addData: AdditionalDto[];
}
```

```js
export class AdditionalDto {

  @IsString()
  title: string;

  @IsString()
  sellYn: string;

  @IsEnum(Language)
  language: Language;

  @IsString()
  description: string;
}
```

My code is written as above.
When sending a file and an array of AddDto through swagger, AddDto is in json format.

When received through swagger, if dto.addData is output,

```json
[{"title":"aa", "sellYn":"Y", "language":"en", "description":"description"},{"title ":"bb", "sellYn":"Y", "language":"kr", "description":"description"}]
```

but, cannot used like dto.addData[0] and dto.addData[0].title .
How can I use dto in non-json format?

I want to know how to process file upload and dto in one time,
instead of sending them separately.
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i undestrand correctly your question, but here is what I will try

First, you have to accept on your controller `array-of-an-objects`
Like this:

```
@Body() dto: AddDto[]
```

Then, if you are accepting array of an objects, you have to delete this in you `AddDto` array like object.

```
export class AddDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  firstName?: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsOptional()
  lastName: string;

  @IsOptional()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => AdditionalDto)
  addData: AdditionalDto; // <---- Make it as and object, not array
}
```

And I hope that it will work in the way that you want.

In this case you are available to send multiple files and each file will have it's own properties.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I read it carefully, but it seems to be different from what I inquired about.Simply, I use swagger and I want to send the file and other data dto at the same time. I wonder how to set it up in this case.

Comment: @KunAguero, have you solved your problem? I also have the same trouble uploading a JSON (DTO) and attaching a file.

Comment: @JacobC. no. Couldn't solve this problem. I have separated file upload and dto and used them in different controllers.